# Looping over elements of Json Array

Tags: java, json, jackson

Hi I am new to Json strings and found a lib Jackson that I use to build and process Json strings. How would I loop elements of a Json array in Java the following example:

```
String jsonStr = "[{\"foo\": \"bar\"},{\"foo\": \"biz\"}]";
```

The Jar's that I am using is jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.12.jar and jackson-core-asl-1.9.12.jar.

I did try the following:

```
JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(jsonStr);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// advance stream to START_ARRAY first: jp.nextToken();
// and then each time, advance to opening START_OBJECT
while (jp.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) 
{


}
```

The class Foo:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public String foo;
}
```

Please could any one give me an example how I would loop all the elements. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
Foo[] foos = objectMapper.readValue(json, Foo[].class);
```

Then just loop it as a regular array.